# Validate Username and Password

Tags: dominotogo

How can I validate whether or not a correct username and password has been entered? I would like to prompt a user if their entered username/password did not find a match in the Notes address book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try a NotesView.update() with wrong credentials it will fail, the callback function will get false as first parameter and I assume that it will get a specific error as second parameter.

I don't think you can compare the password with passwords stored in the Domino address book. In Domino, the passwords are only saved as salted hash, and there is no way you can create the same hash value on the iOS device.

Comment: Thanks, Julian. I used NotesView.update() and based on what is returned I am alerting the user. I also made a change in the ynReadView method in dtg_notesview.js to alert with "No network available" before the return statement if the device isn't connected.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the username and password and compare it against the data you stored in your address book. if you are using some encryption the conception is a bit different but you still have to perform a comparison.